# using java to read unicode delimited files

Tags: java, unicode

I have checked encoding table, I think is delimiter is this one ¶ which is  "`0xc2 0xb6`" in `UTF-8`

how should I process this file? (use delimiter to separate fields and read the field value in string array)

Below is the Sample data:

Field 1þ¶þDescriptionþ¶þField 2þ¶þField 3þ¶

Comment: Why don’t you use a `Reader` configured to `UTF-8`? Then, it is completely irrelevant, to which bytes the delimiter was encoded, you can simply refer to the character `'¶'` when processing the resulting `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String[] field = line.replace("þ", "").split("¶");
```

Comment: What’s the purpose of `.replace("þ", "")`?

Comment: @Holger They enclose each field name. I doubt OP wants to hold on to them.

Comment: Hmm, the OP doesn’t even mention them, so it’s unclear whether they shall be removed. But if you derive that requirement from the sample data, a simple `line.split("þ?¶þ?")` will do…